# How do I filter data by attribute using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, asp.net-3.5

How do I only pull  nodes that have **name** that begin with "tag" and end with "DescRes"? I am using a XMLDataSource and GridView (ASP.NET 3.5) to display the XML. Nothing fancy. If values need to be hard-coded in the XSLT, that's fine too.

```
<data name="tagoneCtrlNumberRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>1.</value>
   <comment>A01</comment>
</data>
<data name="tagoneCtrlDescRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Hello</value>
   <comment>A01</comment>
</data>
<data name="tagoneCtrlNoteRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Hi</value>
   <comment>A01</comment>
</data>
```

If I start with this XML, I'd like the resultant XML after the XSLT is applied to show:

```
<data name="tagoneCtrlDescRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Hello</value>
   <comment>A01</comment>
</data>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:param name="sortby"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="orderas"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!--<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>-->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data">
                <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortby]|@*[name()=$sortby]" data-type="text" order="{$orderas}"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <data>
            <xsl:attribute name="comment">
                <xsl:value-of select="comment" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ctrlname">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="value" />
            </xsl:attribute>            
        </data>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-line XPath 1.0 expression - solution and its complete XSLT 1.0 - based verification. Detailed explanation is provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 use the standard XPath functions [**`starts-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with) and **[`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-ends-with)**.

In Xpath 1.0 there isn't a function `ends-with()` so you need to use an equivalent XPath 1.0 expression.

**I. XPath 1.0 / XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "*/data[@name[starts-with(.,'tag')
               and
                 substring(., string-length(.)-11) = 'DescRes.Text'
                 ]
        ]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML fragment** (made a well-formed XML document by wrapping it into a single top element):

```
<t>
    <data name="tagoneCtrlNumberRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>1.</value>
        <comment>A01</comment>
    </data>
    <data name="tagoneCtrlDescRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Hello</value>
        <comment>A01</comment>
    </data>
    <data name="tagoneCtrlNoteRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Hi</value>
        <comment>A01</comment>
    </data>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<data name="tagoneCtrlDescRes.Text" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Hello</value>
        <comment>A01</comment>
    </data>
```

**Explanation**: The XPath 1.0 equivalent of `ends-with($s, $end)` is this:

```
substring($s, string-length($s) - string-length($end) +1) = $end
```

**II. XPath 2.0 /XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "*/data[@name[starts-with(.,'tag')
               and
                 ends-with(.,'DescRes.Text')
                 ]
        ]
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Here we use the Xpath 2.0 standard function `ends-with()`**

Comment: Only one question. Does it have to be in that exact format? I was hoping to adapt it to what I already have. Right now, I have the attributes mapped in my XSLT to my GridView.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: No solution is absolute and most solutions at SO while solving a problem in a specific way, can be re-used/adapted in/to a class of similar problems. In this particular case, you can re-use the gained knowledge in any scenario asking for `ends-with()`. Of course, you need to have at least a basic knowledge of XPath and this is true for any programming language you are given a solution in.

Comment: Fair enough. At least, I have a base to work from. Thanks, Dimitre.